# Git blame: How to find a commit where a cluster of lines is introduced?

Tags: git

Git blame finds a commit where each line is introduced.  Similarly, can it find a commit where a cluster of lines is introduced?

For example, consider the following changes:

Commit 1 (add a pgettext call):

```
pgettext(
  "context1",
  "msgid1"
)
```

Commit 2 (add another pgettext call):

```
pgettext(
  "context1",
  "msgid1"
)

...

pgettext(
  "context2",
  "msgid2"
)
```

Commit 3 (remove the two pgettext calls and add another):

```
pgettext(
  "context1",
  "msgid2"
)
```

If I run `git blame` at Commit 3 or its descendant, it blames the lines with `"context1"` and `"msgid2"` for Commit 1 and 2.

```
Commit 1: pgettext(
Commit 1:   "context1",
Commit 2:   "msgid2"
Commit 2: )
```

Meanwhile the *pair* of the lines with `"context1"` and `"msgid2"` is introduced by Commit 3.  So, my expected behavior is that the input is the following string

```
  "context1",
  "msgid2"
```

and the result is `Commit 3`.  How can I achieve that?

Comment: That won't fly, to the best of my knowledge. From commit 2 to 3, git does _not_ see it as the previous 2 blocks being removed and a 3rd added. To it, it was just the intermediate lines that were deleted. You could get that output if you deleted the first 2 blocks in a commit and added the 3rd in a following commit.

Comment: It's important to understand that git stores the *whole file* for each commit (with some optimization, so that it doesn't actually waste as much space as this makes it sound like) and any display of "diffs" is calculate *after the fact* when you ask for a diff or a blame. And the default algorithm to classify these changes doesn't consider "blocks" like this. At least for diffs there are alternative algorithms available, which consider common block-like structures like this, but I don't know if they can be applied to a simple blame.

Comment: Try `git log -S <string>`

Comment: I think `git log -n 1 -S <string>` (or `git log -n 1 -S <regex> --pickaxe-regex`) is what I wanted.  Thank you!